# Название DB с дефисом

Tags: mysql

Возможно ли создать базу данных с дефисом в названии? Если да, то как? Спасибо

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35592181/10235013

Comment: При создании базы в названии поставить дефис.

Comment: Просто поражают такие вопросы. Прям не судьба попробовать, прежде чем вопрос задавать.

Answer (score 0):

Приведу перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592034/) с enSO упомянутый в комментарии к вопросу пользователем @Yaant

Согласно [документации mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html) названия схем могут состоять из буквенно-числовых символов, нижнего подчеркивания и знака доллара. Для использования других ANSI-символов название таблицы необходимо заключать в одинарные обратные кавычки:

```
`database-name`
```

Но в bash они имеют другое значение и используются для [подстановки команд](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html). В bash также есть несколько типов строк - в двойных и одинарных кавычках. Разница между ними в том, что в двойных кавычках осуществляется обработка переменных и подстановка команд, а в одинарных нет. Таким образом можно использовать обратные одинарных кавычки вместе с семантикой mysql в одинарных кавычках:

```
mysql -e 'CREATE DATABASE `db-name`;'
```

но нужно экранировать их использование при использовании в двойных кавычках, чтобы bash не интерпретировал их как командные действия:

```
mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE \`table-db\`;"
```

Если вы хотите получить использование название базы данных хранящейся в переменной ее нужно поместить вне строки в одинарных кавычках, например так:

```
mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE \`$dbname\`;"
```

или так:

```
mysql -e 'CREATE DATABASE `'$dbname'`;'
```